# Will a photon detector detect vacuum photons?

Tags: quantum-electrodynamics

Since photons are continually being created in the vacuum. Or to put it another way since the vacuum energy of the electromagnetic field is non-zero. Should a photon detector in empty space detect vacuum photons?

For example, if we locked the photon detector inside a hollow lead cube and sucked all the air out.

We might get photons emitted from the lead itself.

But then are some of the photons detected just vacuum photons?

It's hard to phrase this question because there's no way to create a truly empty space!

Would it appear just like loop-corrections to the photons emitted from the walls of the lead cube?

Comment: You need to read this: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_particle and think about how bright "empty"  space would be if real photons were produced by this mechanism

Comment: This might be of interest to you, but note the caveats https://www.nature.com/news/a-vacuum-can-yield-flashes-of-light-1.12430

Comment: virtual photons are detectable in accelerated frames (Unruh effect) or if a conducting wall is moving https://www.nature.com/articles/nature10561 Presumably there are many more situations where this can occur that physicists have not imagined yet. Imagination seems to be cautiously nipped in the bud in academic environments, specially these days